# On AIX system, how to insert data to file at certain line

Tags: sed, aix

On an AIX test system, I would like to insert some data to a file at certain line. I have tried using sed command `sed "5i some_data" somefile.txt` but failed. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happened when it "failed?" Just the original text? Error message? Just the some_data? Are you sure somefile.txt had more than five lines?

Comment: @mpez0 error is "sed: 0602-404 Function 5i some data cannot be parsed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` is better for editing streams; you can use a scriptable text editor on files. Example with `ed` or `ex`:

```
ed somefile.txt <<EOE
5i
some data
.
wq
EOE
```

That breaks down what is happening more explicitly.

Comment: you can silence some of ed's output with `ed -s`

Comment: @BlackForest - do you not have "ed" on your system? Try "ex".

Comment: `ed` and `ex` are both part of the `bos.rte.edit` package, which I believe is installed by default. "Does not work" should be clarified to indicate what was tried and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

[AIX sed](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/sed.htm) is strict in [requiring a newline with the `i` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html):

```
cp somefile.txt somefile.txt.orig
sed '5i\
some_data' somefile.txt.orig > somefile.txt
```

Where the standard indicates:

```
[1addr]i\
text
Write text to standard output.
```